# Laravel won't resolve model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, route-model-binding

I'm building an application to track expenses, using laravel 5.8 as the back-end.
When I try to access the show method on my controller, I find laravel is giving me a fresh instance of the model instead of fetching the one matching the id provided.

I tried checking the actual value that was taking from the URI, which was correct and also manually querying to see if it had any results, which it did.
I also checked all names where written properly (checking plurals and singulars).

The index method with `return Expense::all()` works just fine.

The model is empty, it just has a `$guarded` attribute.

This is the routes file located at *routes/api.php*

```php
Route::apiResource('expenses', 'ExpenseController');
```

This is the controller located at *app/Http/Controllers/ExpenseController.php*

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Expense;

class ExpenseController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Expense $expense)
    {
        return Expense:findOrFail($expense->getKey()); // key is null since it's a fresh model
    }
}
```

```php
public function show($expense)
{
    //dd($expense); //Shows the id given on the URI
    return Expense::where('id', $expense)->firstOrFail(); //Works!
}
```

Expense model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Model;

class Expense extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];
}
```

I'm expecting to get the JSON data of the model with the given id, but instead I'm getting a fresh model with `$exists = false`, not getting any 404 errors.

I'm also using laravel/telescope and it shows the request finished with a 200 code and no queries made.

Reponse when using dd

```
Expense {#378 ▼
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

This is the entire class *app\Model.php*

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

/**
 * Class Model
 * @package App
 * @method static static|null find($id)
 * @method static static findOrFail($id)
 * @method static static create(array $data)
 * @method static Collection all()
 */
class Model extends BaseModel
{

}
```

Fix: I was missing the web middleware in the RouteServiceProvider

Comment: If you're using `Expense $expense`, you don't need to query for `Expense`; you already have it via `$expense`...

Comment: Have you tried accessing `/api/expenses/1` and made sure that there's at least one Expense record in your database?

Comment: Both show methods are / were in the controller. The first uses the route model binding `show(Expense $expense)` and the second doesn't `show($expense)`. They're not there at the same time, just trying different things

Comment: @CaddyDZ Yes, that's the result I'm getting from that URI. Querying the database using the where method works just fine.

Comment: Can you try running `php artisan route:list` and see if there's something wrong?

Comment: Looks pretty right to me.


@show  |  GET|HEAD  |  api/expenses/{expense}    |    expenses.show  |  App\Http\Controllers\ExpenseController

Comment: Please show App\Model class relevant code.

Comment: Done, the class is empty, it's just a help for the IDE and to allow some changes in the future

Comment: Implicit binding is not working and the problem does not show up, IMHO, in the code posted.

Comment: Do you get an error/404 if you try to access an expense that DOESN'T exist? `/api/expenses/1000` or so?

Comment: @kerbholz Same thing using a non existing id

Comment: What do you get with `show(Expense $expense) { dd($expense); }`? As @TimLewis said, that should be enough.

Comment: It shows what's under _Reponse when using dd_

Comment: Fixed: I was missing the web middleware in the RouteServiceProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm using the *routes/api.php* file for my routes, I needed to change the **api** middleware to the **web** one in the RouteServiceProvider file located inside *app/Providers*.

Piece of code needed to be changed:

```php
/**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             //->middleware('api')
             ->middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

Comment: Check that you have the `'bindings'` value in the `api` key of `$middlewareGroups` in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.